# Take data from a file and add it to the Linked List in C

Tags: c, list, file, linked-list, fopen

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
    
struct Friend{
    char name[50];
    char surname[50];
    char gender;
    char date[50];
    struct Friend * next;
};

struct Friend* initialize(char *);

int main(){
    char name[100];
    printf("ENter the name of the file\n")
        gets(name);
    struct Friend * head;
    head=initialze(name);
    
}

struct Friend * initialize(char *name){
    FILE * ffile;
    ffile=fopen(name,"r");
    if(ffile==NULL)
        exit(1);
}
```

Here are my Function initizaliations in C. I need to take and open a file (example of how the file looks is below), and make a LINKED LIST which holds the NAME, SURNAME, GENDER AND DATE OF BIRTH of each person, and return the (HEAD pointer) start address of the linked list. I have finished the task by taking one character at a time, by having 3 nested while loops. But as you might have guessed this is a very inefficient solution.

The name of the file doesn't matter since I am prompting the used to write it. But here is how the FILE LOOKS LIKE

> John;Lenny;M;13/01/1978;
>
> Josh;Bush;M;15/05/1989;
>
> Anjelica;Victoria;F;20/10/1990;

So as you see we have a semicolon(;) after each element

Comment: Have you had any performance issues?

Comment: Please stop using the obsolete `gets` and use `fgets` (which also reads any newline). Then you could use `strtok` (and variants) or `strsep` to split the input string.

Comment: Note: the `struct` members show the input could be about 150 characters, but the input string has only 99.

Comment: This is not your real code (`initialze`).

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this a bit different.
you can either read the entire file to a buffer or read it and store after every time you encounter "\n"
Then you have to have a method that creates a node of the desired structure and fill in the data from the current line you've just read.

For example:

```
void create(Friend* Head)
{
  struct Friend *new_node = malloc(sizeof(Friend));

  new_node->whatever = whatever;

  Head->Next = new_node;

}
```

Comment: Don't cast `malloc()`.